# groovy project zero error when accesing database

Tags: json, rest, groovy, project

I installed project zero and created project from repository with employees. It works fine with this part:

```
URL employeeURL = new URL(getAbsoluteUri("/resources/employees"));
employees = zero.json.Json.decode(employeeURL);
```

but when I change it to

```
URL temasUrl      = new URL(getAbsolureUri("/resources/teams"));
URL teams = zero.json.Json.decode(teamsURL);
```

I get an error although the resource is accessible through browsers
this is the error

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:No signature of method: charts.getAbsolureUri() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [/resources/teams]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAbsolureUri()` in the second snippet looks like it should be `getAbsoluteUri()` based on the first snippet.

Comment: Thank you that's it very simple mistake. Sometimes there is a need for someone else to look at your code. Thanks a lot man.